# How to hide categories, if nested menu is empty after search?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I made a simple search with Vue which supposed to find an item from listed menu. Although, search works perfect, I need to make some trick. Basically, after searching an item, there will be displayed items with categories. Categories and items are nested. Sometimes, after searching, our categories could be empty. In this case, I need to hide those categories, which doesn't have suitable searched item.

I have an idea, to making this work is returning searched items from computed property. Then using foreach we can hide some categories. Unfortunately, computed property doesn't return searched items.

```
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      return this.menu.filter(item => {
          return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  },
```

Let's take an example on this fiddle. Try to search "Green", you will still see Soups category with empty div.

My question is how can I hide that "soups" category?

[Simple Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za7s9j6c/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another computed property, based on `filteredItems`:

```
filteredCategories: function() {    
    return this.filteredItems.map( (item) => item.cat_id )
}
```

And then use it in `v-if`:

```
<div v-for="(c, index) in categories" :key="index" v-if="filteredCategories.includes(c.id)">
```

Comment: It was perfect solution! Thank you!